# Group statements in when expression while using sealed classes in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following piece of code in my app:

```
...
when (wrapper) {
        is WrapperOne  -> when (val action = wrapper.action) {
          is ChangeCategory -> EventBus.getDefault().post(CategoryChangeEvent(action.category))
          ShowWelcomeScreen -> navigator.navigateToWelcomeScreen()
        }
        is WrapperTwo -> when (val action = wrapper.action) {
          is ChangeCategory -> EventBus.getDefault().post(CategoryChangeEvent(action.category))
          ShowWelcomeScreen -> navigator.navigateToWelcomeScreen()
        }
        is WrapperThree -> navigator.navigateToDetail(wrapper.item)
...
```

Wrapper is a sealed class with several data classes inside.
Action is another sealed class with a data class (ChangeCategory) and an Object (ShowWelcomeScreen)
As you can see, the code inside the first two cases of the first when is duplicated. Is there a way to group it like you can do with enums?

Something like:

```
when (wrapper) {
        is WrapperOne, WrapperTwo  -> when (val action = wrapper.action) {
          is ChangeCategory -> EventBus.getDefault().post(CategoryChangeEvent(action.category))
          ShowWelcomeScreen -> navigator.navigateToWelcomeScreen()
        }
       
        is WrapperThree -> navigator.navigateToDetail(wrapper.item)
```

Comment: You're just missing an `is`: `is WrapperOne, is WrapperTwo ->`

Comment: if I do that, then I get an error: Uresolved reference action in wrapper.action

Comment: WrapperOne and WrapperTwo need to inherit from a common parent with the `action` property. In fact, then you only need one `is` check, for that parent.